# How to query entities/nodes that does not have the field "field_parent" with EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm using the Entity reference module and want to select all nodes that has no parent defined. I'm trying with:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$children = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'page')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_parent', 'target_id', null, 'IS NULL')
    ->execute();
```

.. but that does not give anything as the field "field_parent" is missing and not set to NULL. If I use IS NOT NULL I get all nodes that has a parent.

How can I select all nodes that has no parent (or is missing the field "field_parent")?

---

Thanks to Clive I managed to solve this in the following way:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$children = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'page')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->addTag('filter_no_parent')
    ->execute();

/**
* Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
*/
function mymodule_query_filter_no_parent_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_parent', 'p', 'node.nid = p.entity_id');
    $query->isNull('p.field_parent_target_id');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (natively) I'm afraid. An `EntityFieldQuery` doesn't have support for `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

There are workarounds, however, essentially by adding a tag to the query and implementing a query alter hook, in which you add the required `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` statement.

See [EntityFieldQuery does not support isNull or isNotNull](http://drupal.org/node/1157006) for a code example. I've used that code before with good results.

Comment: It worked fine once I understood how to name the tables and fields in the hook_query_TAG_alter function :-)

Comment: Note: Drupal 8 adds the `exists` and `notExists` methods.